# Unable to stop streams service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-streams

I'm unable to stop the bluemix streams service. Clicking the OK button appears to do nothing.

[image]

I have tried Chrome and Firefox - both do not work.  The console shows the following errors in Chrome:

[image]

Any ideas will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try a browser on a different operating system.  I'm able to start and stop the service when using Firefox on OS/X, but not on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS).

Comment: What version of Firefox and Chrome had the issue?

Comment: I created an Ubuntu 14.04.3 virtual machine, and cannot reproduce the issue using the default Firefox version. Is the issue still occurring for you?